# wordpress function to compare shipping location

Tags: wordpress

I am modifying my wordpress functions.php file so that when an order is placed, the email gets sent to a different email address depending on the shipping address of the order.

This below code works to change the recipient...

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'wc_change_admin_new_order_email_recipient', 1, 2);

function wc_change_admin_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
global $woocommerce;

$recipient = "email@domain.com";

return $recipient;
}
```

But now when I try and put in some logic around shipping country it doesn't work, infact whole site doesn't load and I have to go through cpanel to roll back the changes.

```
// Change new order email recipient for registered customers
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'wc_change_admin_new_order_email_recipient', 1, 2);

function wc_change_admin_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
global $woocommerce;

if ($order->shipping_country=="AU")
    $recipient = "email@domain.com";
} else {
    $recipient = "email2@domain2.com";
}


return $recipient;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details specifically the error details. I hope you have debug mode on. It will help you to see the error.

Comment: The code I put there with the if statement is just a random guess by me, I don't really know PHP code or wordpress and this was cobbled together from searching online. So I'm looking for someone that would know about this and can show me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there was a typo in your code. You are missing a curly brace after your if statement. The logic seems to be correct. Try the following code and let us know if it works.

Also I recommend you to [turn on WP_DEBUG in your WordPress installation](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG). It will help you to catch errors more quickly. You can always turn it off when you publicly launch the website.

```
// Change new order email recipient for registered customers
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'wc_change_admin_new_order_email_recipient', 1, 2);

function wc_change_admin_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {

    global $woocommerce;

    if ($order->shipping_country=="AU") {
        $recipient = "email@domain.com";
    }

    else {
        $recipient = "email2@domain2.com";
    }

    return $recipient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Add everything below to your current theme's functions.php:
// The email to send can be changed by using a different filter in place of 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order'

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'wc_new_order_cash_on_delivery_recipient', 10, 2 );
function wc_new_order_cash_on_delivery_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {

    if ( 'AU' == $order->shipping_country ) {

        $recipient = "test@test.com";
    }


    return $recipient;
}
```